# using all possible file combos in a directory as input for python

Tags: python

I have a program in `python` which uses two files as inputs - and calculates the similarity between them. I want to use all possible combinations of files in a directory as input. How can this be done using  `python` expanding upon the script that I already have?

I know there are tools such as `glob` which iterate through an entire file. However, what can I do to also create all of the different file combinations?

Also, as @hcwhsa  and @Ashish Nitin Patil how can `itertools` be combined with `glob`??

Thank you for any insight.

Further detail:

My code requires 2 inputs that are identical (I have a directory of approx 50 of these files).
Each input is 3-tab separated column (value1, value2, weight).
Essentially with this information I calculate jaccard coefficient as found [here](http://love-python.blogspot.it/2012/07/python-code-to-compute-jaccard-index.html):

```
def compute_jaccard_index(set_1, set_2):
    return len(set_1.intersection(set_2)) / float(len(set_1.union(set_2)))
```

I want to calculate this coefficient for all the possible combinations of files in the directory.
As of now, I called each file locally as:

```
with open('input_file1', 'r') as infile_B:
with open('input_file2', 'r') as infile_B:
```

My goal is to iterate the function over all possible combinations of files in the directory.

Comment: [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: That is exactly what the code in my answer gives you - all filename combinations of all files in a given folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, that is exactly what I need - then using this should also use each file combination as various inputs? That is where I was not sure if I needed something like `glob` also. With your solution, all possible combinations of `input1` and `input2` will be created and used directly by the program? That is the main question - I am sorry if I did not express myself clearly.

Comment: Can you provide a list of sample input, and expected output? I still think that my answer answers the first part of your question - it outputs every possible combination of files in a folder. If I understand [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) correctly, it is a tool that can filter out specific files for you, not a tool that iterates over a file.

Comment: Thanks @SteinarLima your solution worked great for my code. I latched my `with open()` files directly into your snippet and with a few slight modifications to integrate it (there was a small problem with a `float` and the iteration) but then I realized it was because I had the script stored in the same directory as the file to iterate over. Once I stored the script in another location and called to the directory works like a charm. One small warning to Mac osX users (like me). For some reason, when I saved my file (with TextMate) a hidden .DS_Store file was created in the directory (....)

Comment: (...) although it is hidden, my script considered it as part of the iterable files. So I had to delete it from the terminal -- small bug but just to put it out there in case someone else has the small problem. Thanks again!

Comment: If you only want files with a specific extensions, you can alter the filenames line to something like this: `filenames = [os.path.join(path, entry) for entry in entries if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, entry)) and entry.split('.')[-1] == 'py']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet compares all files in `path`.

```
import os
from itertools import combinations

path = r'path/to/dir'
entries = os.listdir(path)
filenames = [os.path.join(path, entry) for entry in entries if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, entry))]

for (file1, file2) in combinations(filenames, 2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
        # Compare the files
```

In Python 3, it may be done a bit more elegant.

```
import os
from itertools import combinations

path = r'path/to/dir'
root, _, rel_filenames = next(os.walk(path))
full_filenames = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in rel_filenames]

for (file1, file2) in combinations(full_filenames, 2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
        # Compare the files
```

Comment: this is great - i am still just not seeing very clearly how to link this with `glob`

Comment: I haven't used glob, so I wouldn't know that. What is it specifically you want to do? It might help if you provide us with some of the code you already have.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
import os
for file_1, file_2 in itertools.combinations(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), 2):
    print(file_1, file_2)
    # compare the files
```

Replace `os.getcwd()` with your directory path.

Comment: using this will, for example: create all possible combinations of input1 and input2?

Comment: This will also output combinations with subdirs.